# Can't pip install django-dash

Tags: python, django, command

I have django and dash installed but not django-dash. Any ideas why this wont work?

I've tried both:

```
pip install django_plotly_dash
pip install django-dash
```

Command Prompt Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django_plotly_dash (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django_plotly_dash
```

NEW ERROR:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/django-plotly-dash/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/django-plotly-dash/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/django-plotly-dash/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/django-plotly-dash/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/django-plotly-dash/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django-plotly-dash/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django-plotly-dash/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-plotly-dash (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-plotly-dash
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Did you try with `pip3 install django_plotly_dash`?

Comment: New error posted (it's the same error for django_plotly_dash)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an underscore, but a dash.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org  django-plotly-dash
```

Comment: @RCarmody can you try again after my edit?